# How to substitute a pattern in Makefile.am

Tags: makefile, autotools

I have an application with several subdirectories, which I want to compile non-recursive. For this I have seperated all sorucefiles from the subdirectories into several variables, which I then use in the final collection of sources. Something like this:

```
GUI_SOURCEFILES = Gui/MainWindow.cc \
                  Gui/StatusBar.cc
...
foo_SOURCES = $(GUI_SOURCEFILES) \
              $(DATABASE_SOURCEFILES) \
              main.cc
```

Now however this forces me to write `Gui/` for all gui sourcefiles and `Db\` in front of all database files. I think it should be possible to create this prefix automaticall, but I cannot find a way to do this correctly. I tried the usual make way:

```
GUI_SOURCEFILES = MainWindow.cc \
                  StatusBar.cc
...
foo_SOURCES = $(GUI_SOURCEFILES) \
              $(patsubst %,Gui/%,$(DATABASE_SOURCEFILES)) \
              main.cc
```

But autotools will not compile this `Makefile.am` at all.

Is there a way to get autotools to do this for me?

Comment: What about `$(addprefix Gui/, $(DATABASE_SOURCEFILES))`?

Comment: @dma_k: this has the same problem: `src/Makefile.am:12: addprefix Gui/, $(GUI_SOURCEFILES: non-POSIX variable name` `src/Makefile.am:12: (probably a GNU make extension)`. I think there must be a very specific autotools/m4 way to do this, but I have never used either to a great extend. All Makefile ways are probably out of question.

Comment: @LiKao: Some traditional makefile constructs like suffix substitution also work in automake. However, I don't know a *prefix* method.

Comment: You issue is also mentioned in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167887). I am surprised as well. General advise is: update `autotools` to latest version and make sure that `make` is the only one and it is GNU make. Looking [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/cilkplus/libgomp/Makefile.am) and [there](http://caca.zoy.org/browser/libpipi/trunk/ThePimp/Makefile.am?rev=2940) I think you have an environment issue. Are you running Linux?

Comment: @dma_k: Yes, I am on kubuntu 11.4 using autotools version 2.67 from 2010. Seems rather recent to me. There is no other make installed, so this should not confuse autotools. I think with the examples you linked to the parts where `addprefix` or `patsubst` are used are passed to the final Makefile and not processed by autotools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way here, all filenames must be available at automake time, and that precludes certain make-time like functions (non-portable at that).

Comment: The filenames are fully available. I just don't want to explicitly add the directory prefix each time. That is all. I guess I am out of luck with autotools for this.

Comment: automake could expand *$(addprefix...)* provided the argument is constant and known at AM time, just like it does with *include*, but alas, it does not do it currently, which leads to "if you can cook up a patch, you can try submitting".